# Filters not working on the new navigation bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

This issue started this evening. I applied filters and it shows notification of "2 new questions".

[image: screen shot 1]

When I clicked the notification, it disappears. And the old questions remain.

[image: screen shot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3920` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3025` (stackoverflow.com).

Comment: but i am facing now

Comment: @Sajeetharan maybe build went wrong, I'd wait for next one. (might be tomorrow)

Comment: I can confirm it's fixed - did you refresh your page?